# Regex - I want my string to end with 2 special character

Tags: javascript, regex

I've been trying to make a regex that ends with 2 special characters, but I couldnt find solution. Here is what i tried, but it seems like it is not working.

```
/.[!@#$%^&*]{2}+$/;
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Remove the `.` and `+`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew that's fast.....

Comment: It should work. Show some cases that don't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this regex:

```
^.*[!@#$%^&*]{2}$
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/fVTQjy/12)

```js
const regex = /^.*[!@#$%^&*]{2}$/;
const str = `abc@#\$`;
let m;

if(str.match(regex)) {
console.log("matched");
}
else
  console.log("not matched");
```

Comment: isn't it also match more than 2 special characters like `abc$#@!`?

Comment: op said " ends with 2 special characters" . Did not say there can not be any other special character present in the full string

Comment: _trying to make a regex that ends with **2 special characters**,_..... I guess OP does mentioned.

Comment: yes that ends with 2 speical character, doesn't mean can not start or can not have any more speical character in the rest of the body

Comment: Well, the order of letters (besides last 2) are not defined. It can go like numStrCharNumNumStrChar... (infinitely), but it has to end with 2 consecutive special characters. The answer covers it all. Thanks mate, cheers

Answer (score 0):

The `/.[!@#$%^&*]{2}+$/` regex matches

- `.` - any character but a line break char
- `[!@#$%^&*]{2}+` - in PCRE/Boost/Java/Oniguruma and other regex engines supporting possessive quantifiers, it matches exactly 2 cars from the defined set, but in JS, it causes a "Nothing to repeat"  error
- `$` - end of string.

To match any string ending with 2 occurrences of the chars from your defined set, you need to remove the `.` and `+` and use

```js
console.log(/[!@#$%^&*]{2}$/.test("#@"))
```

Or, if these 2 chars cannot be preceded by a 3rd one:

```js
console.log(/(?:^|[^!@#$%^&*])[!@#$%^&*]{2}$/.test("#@"))
//           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

The `(?:^|[^!@#$%^&*])` non-capturing group matches start of string (`^`) or (`|`) any char other than `!`, `@`, `#`, `$`, `%`, `^`, `&`, `*` (`[^!@#$%^&*]`)